# jsf 2 ui:include .html give error "XML Parsing Error: no element found"

Tags: html, jsf-2, xhtml, uiinclude

I include a header.html (not .xhtml) to my page, but when I preview my page, it give me error "XML Parsing Error: no element found". I do know that it is the tag no properly closed issue, but since my header page is a html file, not a xhtml file, it shouldn't must close the tag, am I right?

If I do close all the meta tag in my header.html, my page is working fine, but I wish to know that is it a must close all the tag properly in html file if I include them in jsf2, thanks.

header.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title>Header</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
  </head>
  <body>header content</body>
</html>
```

welcome1.xhtml

```
<ui:include src="header.html" />
<p>welcome page</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Oracle's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/ui/include.html), `<ui:include>` is used to `encapsulate and reuse content among multiple XHTML pages`. The `src` attribute is expected to point to a well-formed XML document. Even if you want to include `.html` pages, you need to make sure **all** tags are closed properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you look more closely, you will see the closing `<html>` tag in you header.html, which should end the HTML document, as you can see in [Structure of an HTML document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html). This way, when you include the file in the final view you break that contract.

In JSF you'd be better off using the templating option of facelets. For example in a master template you can make insert points, like the scripts section, and later define inserted contents in template client pages (final views). Kickoff example can be found [in this tutorial by mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-templating-with-facelets-example).

Comment: yes I'm using the template way in my project, but I just no show out in this question. But, because this header.html is provided from a third party, so I'm not allow to modifiy the content, so it is not possible to put in the <ui:composition>

My problem was why all the html tag must be close properly in the header.html page so that my welcome page just will be working fine?